# Test Class for triggers 1

Tags: apex, trigger, unit-test

I have written a trigger and trying to write a test class for it.I am not getting the code coverage.
Can u pls help me where i am going wrong

### Trigger

```
trigger ProfileSkillUser_AfterInsert on ProfileSkillUser (after insert,before delete) {

     set<Id> deleteId = new set<Id>();   
     List<CollaborationGroupMember> newcgm = new list<CollaborationGroupMember>();
     List<CollaborationGroupMember> oldcgm = new list<CollaborationGroupMember>(); 

     List<ProfileSkill> TelematicId = [SELECT Id,Name FROM ProfileSkill WHERE Name = 'Telematics'];     
     List<ProfileSkill> InfoReqId = [SELECT Id,Name FROM ProfileSkill WHERE Name = 'Information Request'];

     List<CollaborationGroup> TelematicCollaboationId = [SELECT Id,Name FROM CollaborationGroup WHERE Name = 'Telematic collaboration'];
     List<CollaborationGroup> InfoReqCollaborationId = [SELECT Id,Name FROM CollaborationGroup WHERE Name = 'Information Request Collaboration'];

        if(trigger.isinsert){
            for (ProfileSkillUser ps : Trigger.new){

                       If(ps.ProfileSkillId == TelematicId[0].Id){ 
                            CollaborationGroupMember  cgm = new CollaborationGroupMember();
                            cgm.CollaborationGroupId=TelematicCollaboationId[0].Id;
                            cgm.MemberId= ps.UserId;                        
                            cgm.CollaborationRole='Standard';  
                            newcgm.add(cgm);
                            } else
                       If(ps.ProfileSkillId == InfoReqId[0].Id){ 
                            CollaborationGroupMember  IRC = new CollaborationGroupMember();
                            IRC.CollaborationGroupId=InfoReqCollaborationId[0].Id;
                            IRC.MemberId= ps.UserId;                        
                            IRC.CollaborationRole='Standard';  
                            newcgm.add(IRC);
                            }

                        }
                        insert newcgm;
                    }


        if(Trigger.isdelete){
                for (ProfileSkillUser pr : Trigger.old){ 

                        If(pr.ProfileSkillId == TelematicId[0].Id){ 
                            deleteId.add(pr.UserId);                    
                            CollaborationGroupMember  cg = new CollaborationGroupMember();
                            CG = [select id from CollaborationGroupMember where MemberId IN :deleteId and CollaborationGroupId = :TelematicCollaboationId[0].Id];
                            oldcgm.add(cg);
                            }else
                        If(pr.ProfileSkillId == InfoReqId[0].Id){ 
                        deleteId.add(pr.UserId);                    
                        CollaborationGroupMember  cg = new CollaborationGroupMember();
                        CG = [select id from CollaborationGroupMember where MemberId IN :deleteId and CollaborationGroupId = :InfoReqCollaborationId[0].Id];
                        oldcgm.add(cg);
                        }                      

                    }
                    delete oldcgm;
                }
        }
```

### test class

```
@istest
public class ProfileSkillUser_AfterInsert_TEST {
    static testMethod void ProfileSkillUser_AfterInsert(){

        //Insert User
        Profile pf= [Select Id from profile where Name='System Administrator']; 

        String orgId=UserInfo.getOrganizationId(); 
        String dateString=String.valueof(Datetime.now()).replace(' ','').replace(':','').replace('-','') ;
        Integer RandomId=Integer.valueOf(Math.rint(Math.random()*1000000)); 
        String uniqueName=orgId+dateString+RandomId; 
        User uu=new User(firstname = 'ABC', 
                         lastName = 'XYZ', 
                         email = uniqueName + '@test' + orgId + '.org', 
                         Username = uniqueName + '@test' + orgId + '.org', 
                         EmailEncodingKey = 'ISO-8859-1', 
                         Alias = uniqueName.substring(18, 23), 
                         TimeZoneSidKey = 'America/Los_Angeles', 
                         LocaleSidKey = 'en_US', 
                         LanguageLocaleKey = 'en_US', 
                         ProfileId = pf.Id
                        );
        insert uu;

        //Insert skill
        ProfileSkill PS = new ProfileSkill();
        PS.Name = 'TestSkill';
        Insert PS;

        List<ProfileSkill> TelematicId = [SELECT Id,Name FROM ProfileSkill WHERE Name = 'TestSkill'];     

        //Insert Chatter Group
        CollaborationGroup CG = new CollaborationGroup();
        CG.Name = 'TestSkillGroup';
        Insert CG;

        List<CollaborationGroup> CollaboationId = [SELECT Id,Name FROM CollaborationGroup WHERE Name = 'TestSkillGroup'];

        //Add User to above created skill
        ProfileSkillUser PSU = new ProfileSkillUser();
        //PSU.ProfileSkillId = PS.Id;
        PSU.ProfileSkillId = TelematicId[0].Id;
        PSU.UserId = uu.Id;
        Insert PSU;

        //Add User to above created Group        
        CollaborationGroupMember  CGM = new CollaborationGroupMember();
        //CGM.CollaborationGroupId=CG.Id;
        CGM.CollaborationGroupId=CollaboationId[0].Id;
        CGM.MemberId= uu.Id;                        
        CGM.CollaborationRole='Standard';
        Insert CGM;

        Test.startTest();
        Delete PSU;        
        Test.stopTest();

        }
}
```

Comment: Which specific line(s) are you struggling to cover?

Answer (score 2):

Your inserted data does not match the expectations of your class, resulting in execution not entering your control structures.

Upon both insert and delete, you are looking for two options on your `ProfileSkillUser` record:

```
If(ps.ProfileSkillId == TelematicId[0].Id){
```

or

```
If(ps.ProfileSkillId == InfoReqId[0].Id){
```

These correspond to `ProfileSkill` records whose names are `"Telematics"` and `"Information Request"` respectively.

Your test class creates and inserts a `ProfileSkillUser` that is associated with a `ProfileSkill` whose Name is `"TestSkill"`. As a result, much of the code in your trigger will never execute, because your test data does not match its expected conditions.

I'd really recommend taking some time to read through [How to Write Good Unit Tests](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/How_to_Write_Good_Unit_Tests) or any of the other quality resources that are recommended constantly on Salesforce Stack Exchange. Right now, your test is making no assertions about the behavior of your code, and therefore "proves" nothing about whether it is acting correctly or not. This is often called a smoke test, because it shows nothing beyond whether or not the code crashes in a specific situation (and often not even that, if overzealous exception handlers are in place).

Comment: Hi David,    Thanks for the reply. I will go through the link which you have send.

Comment: I am getting the code coverage as zero. i replaced record names with 'Telematics' but still the coverage is zero.  Can u pls help me where i am going wrong.

Comment: You should be getting non-zero code coverage regardless, if your trigger is executed at all. I would encourage you to use `System.debug()` and review your code coverage highlighting in Developer Console to identify exactly which lines of code are and are not executing.